# mvc application at mvc application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I wrote a simple web application on ASP.NET MVC3 (for example, **app1**). And I now want to write a simple CMS for it (for example, **app2**).

How can I access to folder `app1/Content/` from **app2**, if **app2** is an independed application?

In the future I want to copy **app2** to one of the folders of **app1** (for example, **app2** path will be `C:/app1/app2/`)

Is this approach correct for building sites in ASP.NET MVC3? If not, please, recomend a better approach!

Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, yes, it's not a very good design choice.

If you need some common stuff between the 2 applications, you can use several approaches, the simpliest that comes to my mind is to define in each application a variable in app settings (inside the web.config) pointing to a folder or URL containing the common stuff and use that.

Same thing if you need to use the same DB from more applications: just use the same connection string.

If you really need to make the 2 apps work together for some reasons, you should make one single app and a viable solution could be to split it using Areas.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `Area` not a different project for simple usages. you can find more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793.aspx)

Comment: for complex situations you can take a look at Orchard Project and the way it do that.